# Как пробрасывает порты торрент? C#

Tags: c#

Как можно пробросить порт программно? Чтобы соединить два компьютера напрямую(даже с динамическим ip)? Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Не уверен, но по моему куда то сюда - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333079

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Соединение двух компьютеров напрямую состоит из двух фаз (подзадач), которые обычно решаются отдельно.

### Фаза 1 - обнаружение (discovery)

Чтобы соединиться - надо знать куда соединяться. Иными словами, нужен ip-адрес. Когда клиент соединяется с сервером, обычно используется доменное имя - но при одноранговом соединении, как правило, доменные имена компьютерам не назначены. И даже если назначены - их тоже нужно как-то узнать.

Для этого есть несколько способов.

1. Ввод ip-адреса (или доменного имени) пользователем напрямую. Если в вашем случае предполагается, что этот вариант и будет основным - дальше про обнаружение можно и не читать.
2. Сканирование сети. Разумеется, перебирать ip-адреса и порты не следует: есть более простой способ кооперативного обнаружения - широковещательные пакеты. Можно на одной стороне отправить UDP-пакет на широковещательный адрес, а на другой принять его на известный порт. В старых сетевых играх это был основной способ обнаружения, он неплохо показывает себя в пределах одного сегмента локальной сети.

   - Более современный вариант - отправка пакета на групповой адрес. Гуглить по слову [IGMP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP).
3. Использование общего каталога. Нужно создать сервер, который бы занимался распространением знаний клиентов друг о друге. Примеры: в сетевых играх от Blizzard этим занимаются сервера Battle.Net. В сети bittorrent этим занимаются торрент-трекеры.
4. Использование распределенных хранилищ данных. Гуглить по слову [DHT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

### Фаза 2 - соединение

И так, у нас есть ip-адрес другой стороны, и возможно даже посредник, через которого можно связаться и договориться о технических параметрах соединения.

Отмечу особенно, что нам совершенно не важно, статический или динамический этот адрес. Важно лишь, что он назначен нужному компьютеру - и мы его знаем! Осталось установить соединение.

Тут снова есть варианты.

1. Если один из компьютеров "видит" другой - то он к нему может подключиться напрямую. Отмечу, что имеет смысл пробовать оба варианта, поскольку возможность установления соединения не обязательно симметрична. К примеру, торрент-клиенты умеют работать даже при полностью закрытых для входящих соединений портах - соединяясь с теми, у кого они открыты. Или, другой пример, протокол FTP - в нем соединение для передачи данных может быть открыто как в активном (сервер соединяется с клиентом), так и в пассивном (клиент соединяется с сервером) режимах.
2. Пользователя можно попросить открыть порт вручную.
3. Протокол [UPnP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) позволяет, в том числе, открыть порт на локальном роутере - если он его поддерживает.
4. Если компьютер закрыт NATом - но этот NAT не является симметричным, то можно воспользоваться "багофичей" NAT. Дело в том, что UDP-пакет, отправленный "наружу", открывает случайный порт для приема информации "внутрь". И в некоторых типах NAT этот самый входящий порт доступен не только для того адреса и порта, на которые был отправлен первый пакет. Таким образом, для протокола UDP для некоторых типов NAT можно открыть входящий порт. За это отвечает протокол [STUN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN).
5. Некоторые провайдеры или организации до сих пор предоставляют доступ в интернет через прокси-сервер. HTTP(S) или SOCKS4-прокси в этом плане нам бесполезны, но вот SOCKS5-прокси позволяет открывать порт на прием соединений.
6. Если все совсем плохо - может помочь VPN или туннелирование. Обычно такие вопросы оставляют пользователю - но вот Skype, к примеру, своей популярностью обязан в том числе способности туннелировать трафик через т.н. супер-ноды (супер-нодой может (мог?!) внезапно стать любой компьютер с разрешенными входящими подключениями, толстым каналом и запущенным скайпом).

Comment: очень понравился ответ. но к сожалению я уже выбрал другой. поторопился. =) спасибо, очень много интересного узнал.

Comment: @bigman галочку, как бы, можно и переставить

Comment: неудобно будет перед другим человеком. =)

Comment: @bigman *а передо мной, значит, удобно?* :)

Comment: @bigman галочку вы ставите не столько для отвечающего, сколько для тех кто будет этот вопрос с ответами читать после.

Comment: перепавил галочку. =)

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, и извините если задел в комментариях.