# Простенький чат на MVC.NET c использованием криптографии

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, криптография, decrypt

Допустим есть окно с всего 3мя текст-инпутами: комната, пароль комнаты, ник.
Если все ввести правильно - тебя впускает в чат.

Данные не передаются в открытом виде, все должно идти через SSL конекшн и, конечно же, шифроватся. Никакого больше функционала нести не нужно. Все минималистично.

Возможно, вопросы будут выглядеть глупо, но... Я не работал с шифрованием и .Net MVC в целом :) Так что какие уж есть :)

---

Итак сами вопросы:

1. Возможно ли реализовать чат без посредника-сервера? Фактически, создавший чат стает сервером на который и будут приходить сообщения от других подключившихся? Фактически, что бы сервер только занимался раздачей "пользователей-серверов" если те доступны. Если нет - то пофиг.
2. Какой алгоритм шифрования в даном случае лучше выбрать?
3. С чего возможно начать работу с самим шифрованием для использования в веб-проэктах? Есть ли готовые либы под это?
4. Любые другие подсказки/мысли. Хотя бы по тому в какую сторону гуглить

Мне хотелось бы представлять как это все должно строится хотя бы в общих чертах, что бы мочь задавать более-менее конкретные вопросы. Я прекрасно понимаю что тема сложная, но мне хотелось бы иметь представление с какого ракурса к этому вообще подступать.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Сделайте сначала 1 пункт (или задайте вопрос на эту тему), а потом уже заморачивайтесь над шифрованием. Если оно вам ещё надо останется. Шифрование - сложная тема, в которой легко накосячить. Как говорится - не крути две ручки сразу.

Comment: @Monk не соглашусь. 1й пункт тут опционален, а остальные на одну и тут же тему.

Comment: @PavelMayorov когда нет чата, к чему прикручивать шифрование то?

Comment: А я и не ищу прям конкретного ответа с готовым кодом. Просто дайте пищу для ума, куда копать :) Кроме того, в зависимости от первого пункта - будет менятся подход к остальным. Не так ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По первому пункту. Когда-то такой способ был в инете основным, сейчас же он называется умным словом P2P (peer-to-peer) и считается весьма сложной технологией. Причина - в том, что с целью защиты от вирусов многим пользовательским компьютерам запрещено принимать входящие соединения. А еще у них бывают серые адреса.

Чтобы запустить ваш P2P-клиент, пользователю придется заниматься т.н. "проброской порта". Часто ее можно сделать частично автоматически (см. протоколы UPnP и STUN), но о общем случае она делается вручную. Подробности - тут: [Как пробрасывает порты торрент? C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-c/550569#550569)

---

### По шифрованию.

В простейшей случае вам достаточно настроить https-биндинг в IIS и заменить http:// на https:// в клиенте. Ну и еще получить сертификат. Или сделать самоподписанный и добавить в доверенные.

Ни клиентский, ни серверный код в целом не будут даже знать о том, через защищенное соединение они общаются или нет.

Но когда речь идет о защищенных чатах, такая "криптография" обычно высмеивается. Потому что авторизовать нужно не только сервер, но и клиент. Особенно клиент. А вот авторизация сервера никому не нужна.

Наиболее перспективные алгоритмы сейчас:

- для шифрования сообщений внутри чат-сессии: AES;
- для установления защищенной чат-сессии: ECDH, алгоритм Диффи — Хеллмана над эллиптической кривой;
- для подписи сообщений: ECDSA, алгоритм электронной подписи над эллиптической кривой;
- для криптостойкого хеширования: SHA-3;
- для распространения открытых ключей: PGP.

---

### Связь двух участников

лучше всего налаживать последовательно, вот так:

1. Базовый вариант - просто передача сообщений по защищенному каналу через сервер-посредник. Используются: AES + SHA-3 для генерации ключа из пароля. Т.е. пользователь вводит пароль, он преобразуется в криптоключ, соединение устанавливается. Если на двух концах введут разные пароли - соединиться не получится.

Сервер-посредник просто пересылает шифрованные сообщения и не знает их содержимого.

2. Дальше надо отказаться от общего пароля и использовать ECDH для генерации общего ключа. Полученный ключ надо хешировать (обязательно!) и визуализировать (например, перевести в base-64), чтобы пользователи сверили отпечатки по альтернативному каналу (слабая защита от MitM, слово "альтернативному" - важное, нельзя для этого использовать ваш же чат). Похожим образом сделано в Telegram.

Хеширование ключа обязательно потому что общий ключ нельзя передавать по другим каналам связи ни в какой форме. Иначе вся идея алгоритма Диффи-Хеллмана коту под хвост.

3. Следующий этап - оказаться от ручной сверки отпечатков и использовать алгоритмы асимметричной криптографии (ECDSA) для защиты от подмены сообщений. Для этого придется хранить в списке контактов открытый ключ каждого пользователя. Этот самый ключ придется проверять по альтернативным каналам. Но для его передачи уже можно использовать ваш же клиент: если у двух пользователей есть общий знакомый, они могут "познакомиться" через него.

Тут можно сделеть как в Скайпе, где можно "кинуть" любой контакт из своего списка в чат, где другие пользователи смогут добавить его к себе. Только если в скайпе контакт - это просто логин, то тут контактом будет логин плюс открытый ключ.

Кстати, от логинов на этом этапе можно уже отказаться - открытый ключ является уникальным идентификатором пользователя.

Еще было бы неплохо сохранять в информации о контакте от кого он был получен, на всякий случай.

4. Следующее направление развития - проверка открытых ключей через PGP, как альтернатива проверке по альтернативным каналам.

*Достоинство подобной схемы - после любого этапа можно остановится, получив программу, пригодную в ограниченному применению.*

---

### Связь же нескольких участников (собственно, чат)

можно делать разными способами.

Во-первых, это может быть расширенный алгоритм Диффи — Хеллмана. Недостаток тут в том, что в такой чат нельзя зайти, при изменении состава участников надо начинать чат заново.

Во-вторых, можно использовать общего посредника, которому участники доверяют читать и передавать их сообщения. К нему участники будут подключаться описанным выше способом. Но вот писать сообщения от лица участников лучше не давать: пересылаемые через третье лицо сообщения должны быть помимо шифрования подписаны (при разговоре двух лиц подпись не обязательна).

В-третьих, можно построишь ячеистую (mesh) сеть распространения сообщений. То есть участники каждого чата случайным образом образуют друг с другом связи, после чего сообщения распространяются вдоль этой сети. Подпись тут также обязательна.

В четверных, как упрощение идеи mesh-сети, можно строить полный граф. То есть в чате каждый участник связывается с каждым. В таком случае можно обойтись без подписи.

---

### Аспекты анонимности.

А именно, отличие ситуаций наличия и отсутствия подписи.

От подписанного сообщения невозможно отказаться. Если Боб пишет Алисе "я вчера банк удачно грабанул" и подписывает сообщение своей подписью - то, ежели Алиса его заложит, его песенка спета. Тут есть некоторые юридические нюансы - к примеру, российские суды *обязаны* принимать в качестве свидетельств только ГОСТовскую подпись, открытый ключ которой подтвержден государственным сертификатом - но *могут* принять любую. Ну и законы со временем меняются, а подписанное сообщение - остается.

С другой стороны, Боб может заявить что это было частью разговора об онлайн-игре, и подпись тут не поможет.

Если же по шифрованному симметричному каналу приходит неподписанное сообщение - то Алиса не сможет доказать, что это не она сама написала сообщение якобы от Боба.

С другой стороны, если под видом Алисы с Бобом разговаривал оперативник в присутствии двух понятых - отсутствие подписи ему тоже не поможет.

В целом для официальных переговоров лучше подписывать каждое сообщение (и, может быть, даже включать туда хеши прошлых сообщений в чате), даже если для безопасной доставки этого и не требуется. А для дружеского трепа лучше использовать способы, позволяющие обойтись без подписи.

---

### PS

Если все, что написано выше, не отбило желание попробовать - можете попробовать написать клиент для протокола Tox. Но у этого варианта есть серьезная проблема - тут не получится идти последовательно, пока до конца не допишите - будет нерабочая хрень вместо программы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь обширный и долгий ответ. Если чесно - желание пошатнуло, но, возможно, все же возьмусь за идею. Правда... когда будет больше времени... Здесь разбиратся и разбиратся :)